# how to create a site collection using more than one template in sharepoint 2013.

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sitecollection

I want to create a new site collection merging more than one template together
ex: team site, community and Blog

Is there features to activate or what

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this buy creating a site collection using one template and then activate the other necessary features to get other templates facilities. Like team site etc.

For blog Activate **BlogContent** feature.

For Publishing site activate **Publishing INfrastructure Feature**

Hope this helps

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to know thanks very much for your help
I'll check the features for each template

Comment: Hope to hear that it helped you. Please mark as answer so that it is easy to find answers for others

Comment: I really wanted to, but I still don't have enough point to do so :(